# ColdFusion 2016 call to Java TensorFlow API Could Not Initialize Class

Tags: java, coldfusion, tensorflow, java-native-interface, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to call the TensorFlow Java API from ColdFusion 2016 developer edition on Windows 10 Home.

I took my cues from the TensorFlow [Readme.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/README.md) It uses a platform-specific JNI dll in addition to the jar, so I set up my test like this:

`<cfscript>
    CreateObject("java","java.lang.System").load("C:\\absolutepath\\tensorflow_jni.dll");
    variables.tensorflow = CreateObject("Java","org.tensorflow.TensorFlow");
    WriteDump(variables.tensorflow);
    WriteOutput("I'm running TensorFlow version: " & variables.tensorflow.version());
</cfscript>`

I thought this was going to be a piece of cake when I saw the WriteDump of the object:[image]

but the call to version() just leaves the browser spinning.

The application log shows the following error:
`Could not initialize class org.tensorflow.TensorFlow The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\ColdFusionBuilder2016\ColdFusion\cfusion\wwwroot\CF_TensorFlow\index.cfm, line: 5`

The JNI appears to be loading... When it doesn't, the error message is very clear "Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: windows..."

I'm not really sure what to do at this point. Is there something I need to do to the Java source to make it play nicely with CF?

Comment: Not sure if/how it can be loaded at runtime. What would definitely work is either a) adding the dll path to `java.library.path` or b) copying the dll file into `jre\bin`. Then restarting.

Comment: Ah, looks like it can be loaded at runtime by bundling the dll within the jar. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably figured out, the library first searches the standard locations for the DLL. So adding the path or file to one of those locations (then restarting CF) would definitely work:

- Add the DLL path to the `java.library.path`
- Copy the DLL file into `jre\bin` directory

Looking over [the source and comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/NativeLibrary.java), apparently the DLL can also be bundled *within* the TensorFlow jar itself. The exact path is o/s specific:

```
private static String makeResourceName() {
    return "org/tensorflow/native/"
        + String.format("%s-%s/", os(), architecture())
        + System.mapLibraryName(LIBNAME);
}
```

So instead of using `System.load()`, open the jar and copy the DLL into the appropriate folder. For windows 64bit, the expected path is `org/tensorflow/native/windows-x86_64/tensorflow_jni.dll`.

```
libtensorflow-1.1.0-rc2-with-dll.jar 

  |-- META-INF
  |-- org    
      |-- tensorflow    
          |-- TensorFlow.class
          |-- ... 
          |-- native 
              |-- windows-x86_64
                  |-- tensorflow_jni.dll
```

Comment: Thanks for your diligence, Leigh. I'll  try this when I'm back at my workstation and will report back.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. It was as simple as bundling. In retrospect, I missed a few things that should have jumped out at me. When I tried bundling it the first time, I put it in a folder literally called native/OS-ARCH instead of native/windows-x86_64. I didn't have any luck with the paths you mentioned. I thought the JNI was working fine because I stopped seeing the "Cannot find TensorFlow native library" error once I put the JAR and DLL in the WEB-INF\lib folder, but it still gave the "could not initialize class" error. Bundling, however, worked perfectly.

Comment: I did restart, yes. You just put both directly in that folder - not in subfolders, right?

Comment: (Edit) Yes, no subfolders, but only the DLL file. The .jar I loaded with `this.javaSettings` as usual.